# What is avg_item_size in bt_page_stats?

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to find out what exactly is avg_item_size in bt_page_stats?

I am using postgresql 13.4 with extension pageinspect.

In my case, if index is created on text it is about 20-200 and if it is on integer it is about 700, I am curious why is avg_item_size bigger with integer than text.

Update:

Here are bt_page_stats of my index created on single integer column. [bt_page_stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Oj5.png)

Here is same on [bt_page_items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmPcf.png).
In picture 2 I can see that itemlen prop is 24 and than I have 9 items with itemlen 808. So avg_item_size 729 is from there and it is averagy of all items.

Now I see, that if I have index created on string, there are no tids but on integer there is a lot of data in tids.

After future exploration I found source code of PostgreSQL> https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/postgresql/dir_57dbf4d3eda9e499038b5c7aaccc39c5.html directly to function pageinspect.

I was not sure about tids, but from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-oid.html I found the answer:
tid, or tuple identifier (row identifier). This is the data type of the system column ctid. A tuple ID is a pair (block number, tuple index within block) that identifies the physical location of the row within its table.

But I still do not understand why tids are when I create index on integer and not on text.

Answer (score 1):

`avg_item_size` is the average size of an index entry.

For an index on a single integer column, that should be 16 (if you have duplicates, and you are using v13 or above, it can be less because of index de-duplication).

An index entry in a leaf page will consist of the `t_tid` (address of the row), which is 6 bytes, a 2-byte `t_info` and the `integer` (4 bytes, but really 8 bytes because of alignment). You can use `bt_page_items` to verify that.